# What logic is followed when there are multiple "and/or" statements in a line of code?

Tags: python

In the following piece of code,

```
def makes_twenty(a,b):
     return a+b==20 or a==20 and b==20
```

Why does this input return False[**makes_twenty(20,2)**] while the following input returns True[**makes_twenty(20,0)**]?

Shouldn't the second input return False as b==20 is not being satisfied?
What logic/concept am I missing here?

Comment: The `and` is executed first.  "Order of operations."

Comment: `a+b==20 or (a==20 and b==20)`

Comment: A good term to know here is `operator precedence`. See also the docs: https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#operator-precedence

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can always ask Python to print out how it parses your code using [the `ast` (abstract syntax tree) module](https://docs.python.org/3.10/library/ast.html#module-ast):

```
$ echo 'a+b==20 or a==20 and b==20' | python3 -m ast
Module(
   body=[
      Expr(
         value=BoolOp(
            op=Or(),
            values=[
               Compare(
                  left=BinOp(
                     left=Name(id='a', ctx=Load()),
                     op=Add(),
                     right=Name(id='b', ctx=Load())),
                  ops=[
                     Eq()],
                  comparators=[
                     Constant(value=20)]),
               BoolOp(
                  op=And(),
                  values=[
                     Compare(
                        left=Name(id='a', ctx=Load()),
                        ops=[
                           Eq()],
                        comparators=[
                           Constant(value=20)]),
                     Compare(
                        left=Name(id='b', ctx=Load()),
                        ops=[
                           Eq()],
                        comparators=[
                           Constant(value=20)])])]))],
   type_ignores=[])
```

The tree is a bit verbose, but you can see the topmost operation is `OR`, followed by a nested `AND`, i.e. Python parses your expression as

```
(a+b==20) or (a==20 and b==20)
```

(And, of course, the precedence order [is well documented](https://docs.python.org/3.10/reference/expressions.html#operator-precedence)).

Answer (score 0):

**makes_twenty(20,0)** returns true because the first condition is true;
This is the execution order:
a+b==20 or (a==20 and b==20)